# Populating a dictionary using two for loops in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary using two `for` loops. Here is my code:

```
dicts = {}
keys = range(4)
values = ["Hi", "I", "am", "John"]
for i in keys:
    for x in values:
        dicts[i] = x
print(dicts)
```

This outputs:

```
{0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John'}
```

Why?

I was planning on making it output:

```
{0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'}
```

Why doesn't it output that way and how do we make it output correctly?

Comment: add a print statement in the second for loop

Comment: I tried that the output was still the same

Comment: check the answer i gave

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
dicts = {}
keys = range(4)
values = ["Hi", "I", "am", "John"]
for i in keys:
    dicts[i] = values[i]
print(dicts)
```

alternatively

```
In [7]: dict(list(enumerate(values)))
Out[7]: {0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'}
```

Comment: thank you for your asnwer. thats interesting. because enumerate also gives out numbers right? cool

Comment: I'm wondering since your answer has more votes, is there a reason one might prefer your alt answer to the dict(zip()) answer below? Is there any real different in runtime, or since zip is a special type of enumerate does it just come down to whether we want the dict.keys to be integers or strings?

Answer (score 92):

```
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{0: 'Hi', 1: 'I', 2: 'am', 3: 'John'}
```

Comment: this looks so simple that I am ashamed of the for loops I did. thank you very much

Comment: well it does assume that the keys and values are correctly associated by the same indices...I suppose the for loop also assumes this, but it is slightly more flexible

Comment: @MikePalmice: The Python documentation guarantees that this is the case as long as the dictionary is not mutated in between.

Comment: Perfect, helped me in my project. Thank you very much, Sir.