# how to read print statement and use them in loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

code :

```
import re
import json
#open("sbins.txt","r")  
data = open("sbiiins.txt","r")
contents = data.read().strip()



for i, p in enumerate(re.findall(r'"password":[^"]*"(.*?)"', contents):

        print('{}="{}"'.format(i, p))
```

this code prints outputs this below strings by parsing a text file :

```
1="pass1425-*"
2="pass1234- "
3="pass0*++"
4="pass*-+"
```

i need to use these print statements and use them in loop

for example :

```
ids = (1,2,3,5,6,7,8)

for ind in ids:
     a= ids
      ....
       ....
```

In above code

1 should return pass1425-*

2 should return pass1234-
...

Comment: you can make a dictionary with keys as indexes and values as `passxyz` etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: can i make dict near the print itself ?

Comment: need to pass lots of values cant do it manualy @DeveshKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, use a dictionary.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

```
thisdict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
thisdict["year"] = 2018
```

Your case:

```
thisdict =  {
    "1":"pass1425-*",
    "2":"pass1234- ",
    "3":"pass0*++",
    "4":"pass*-+"
}
print(thisdict["2"])

>>>>pass1234-
```

Comment: can i make and print the dict itself ?

Comment: Yes of course. Ill edit to show you code for your case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280856/populating-a-dictionary-using-for-loops-python

Comment: Youll have to be more specific, i dont know what youre asking in that case.

Comment: `for i, p in enumerate(re.findall(r'"password":[^"]*"(.*?)"', contents):

        print('{}="{}"'.format(i, p))`   this prints the following  `1="pass1425-*"
2="pass1234- "
3="pass0*++"
4="pass*-+"`      . How to store the printed values and use them in loop. in this case i have huge values so cant add them manually to the dict.

Comment: Create a list then use list.append[]